# Display json object properties in parameters list in Swagger UI

Tags: php, json, swagger, swagger-ui

I' writing the docs for web API with swagger, OpenAPI version 3. I use [swagger php package](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) to generate documented json from annotations. I have service, where I send post request to add new user, and requested body is json(so parameters are sent as json object). it has 2 parameters - email and password. 
request body looks like

```
{
   "email": "test@test.com",
   "password": "test"
}
```

here's YAML of swagger

```
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/SignUp'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
```

here's reference schema which contains request parameters (`/components/schemas/SignUp`)

```
SignUp:
  title: SignUp
  description: Adds new user
  type:object
  required:
    - email
    - password
  properties:
    email:
      description: User's email
      type: string
      maximum: 255
      pattern: email
    password:
      description: User's password
      type: string
      maximum: 255
```

here's how it looks in swagger UI
[image]
as you can see on image, requested body is empty(while I have 2 parameters) and this is the issue. if I change the header from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then it will work(it will show all parameters in parameters list). how to make it show json object parameters in that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec is correct and the displayed result in Swagger UI is correct and exactly as expected for OpenAPI 3.0 definitions.

Note there are two sections, "Parameters" (for `parameters`) and "Request body" (for `requestBody`). In OpenAPI 3.0, `parameters` is only used for query parameters, path parameters, request headers and cookies; whereas `requestBody` is displayed in the "Request body" section. You can click "Model" link to view the request body schema with property descriptions.

Comment: thanks for reply. I know about parameters and request body. so its not possible to show them in that list? I have models for it also, where everything is described, but I want to show this in list

Comment: It's not possible in the standard Swagger UI, but Swagger UI is open-source so you can fork and change it as you wish. But keep in mind that users familiar with the standard Swagger UI might get confused if things are displayed in unexpected places.